# Set default coding system = UTF-8

Tags: character-encoding

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1

I want when I save any file to save them (by default) with coding system = **UTF-8**.

So In my **init.el** I has :

```
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-language-environment 'utf-8)
(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

But it not help. When I try to save file (**C-x C-s**) Emacs prompt me: "**Select coding system**"

Comment: What is the type/mode of the file you are saving? Having you tried this with just emacs -Q? I just have `(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)` in my config (Windows 10, Emacs 25.2) and it works fine. Your code also seems fine, so it is likely something else.

Comment: Type mode is Text because file is myfile.txt. I try this (prefer-coding-system 'utf-8-unix) - but it not help. I try  emacs -Q but it also ask me "Select coding system".

Comment: That is strange. What language is Windows 10 configured to use - for input etc - and what kind of characters (e.g. Latin, Cyrillic, Chinese) does your text file contain? PS. I didn't mean to suggest you should use `'utf-8-unix`, `utf-8` should be fine.

Comment: Also - what does "myfile.txt" contain? Text you typed in? Nothing? Text pasted in?

Answer (score 5):

This does it for me:

```
(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
```

See [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_encoding_decoding_faq.html).

Answer (score 3):

I do not know if this can be of help, but I will mention it anyway. When working (mainly in source LaTeX files) with my colleagues  who use a different coding system, nothing I did could persuade Emacs to always read (or save) with the desired encoding.
I found that the only safe way was to add as a first line something like:

```
% -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
```

starting in column 1. You can set the encoding you prefer there, and Emacs will
save (or read) with the prescribed encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `M-x customize` then `Environment > Keyboard > Keyboard Coding System` The docs say 
"This is set at startup based on locale." which may also point you in the direction of what variable to set.